# models.Model field type for list of strings

Tags: django, django-models

What field type would I use to store the following in my MySQL database using `models.Model`?

```
SURVEY_URLS = ['/surveyone/', '/surveytwo/', '/surveythree/', '/surveyfour/', '/surveyfive/', '/surveysix/', '/surveyseven/', '/surveyeight/', '/surveynine/']
```

I have been looking at [Djangos model field field types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types) but nothing seems obvious.

And searching variants of "Django How to store a list in a models.Model" etc. does not show me anything obvious

Comment: Will the list be large? Do you want to do complex database lookups against the list? Or do you just want to store it as a dumb list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a step back and reconsider your design.  I believe what you have is a 'survey' business entity.  So if your model is a survey, it's URL would be an attribute (so would its count, etc...).

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

But generally you wouldn't actually put the model's URL into a field- the URL would be derived from something else, like it's name.  The django [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) would then pass the name into the view which would perform a lookup to get the correct survey.

Anytime you find yourself hard-coding `one`, `two`, `three`, ... there is almost always a much better way to do it.  Don't just support 9 hard-coded surveys- support `n` surveys (where `n` could be 1,000,000).

Answer (score 1):

just convert the list to JSON string and save into `TextField`

```
yourobject.yourfield = json.dumps(SURVEY_URLS)
yourobject.save()
```

to retrieve the list back:

```
import ast
list_again = ast.literal_eval(yourobject.yourfield)
```